# how to get common values of a column(name) from multiple tables using sqlite

Tags: sqlite

I have 5 tables say t1,t2,t3,t4,t5.All these tables have same column name which is 'NAME'. now for each table 'NAME' column is unique but there can be repetation on two or more than two tables. i want to find the common 'NAME' and on which tables they are there.
 After UNION ALL i got something like this[Image after doing UNION ALL](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PWXA6.png)

result should show 'sona' and 'sonali' and also the tables where these values are there

Comment: If you have an answer, write it as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
select 1 
from (
    select name as name from tbl1
    union all
    select name from tbl2
    union all
    select name from tbl3
    union all
    select name from tbl4
    union all
    select name from tbl5
) a
where name = 'someuser'
```

Comment: i want to get the common names and this can be anything so actually i am not comparing name with some fixed falue.

Answer (score 0):

```
"SELECT t1.NAME, '' AS 'TABLE' FROM (select NAME from client1 UNION ALL select NAME from client2  UNION ALL select NAME from client3 "
                "UNION ALL select NAME from client4 UNION ALL select NAME from client5) t1 "
                " WHERE (select count(*) FROM (select NAME from client1 UNION ALL select NAME from client2  UNION ALL select NAME from client3 "
                "UNION ALL select NAME from client4 UNION ALL select NAME from client5) t2 WHERE t1.NAME=t2.NAME)>1 GROUP BY NAME ORDER BY NAME"
```

With this i can find the common name but can't find which table they belong.